# Fedora bleeding edge Perl repo?

Tags: linux, fedora, perl, yum

Are there any Fedora YUM repositories that would contain the very latest stable version of Perl (at the time of writing, 5.18.0)?  The Fedora site says that won't even be shipped stock until Fedora 20.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you just like having shiny new versions to play with, or do you need some new feature in 5.18?

Comment: I think I just used CPAN's upgrade command and saw that a bunch wouldn't upgrade because they're shipped with 5.18.  I don't think there was a hard need, it was more out of curiosity.  Although, it'd be nice to test everything with the new hash item ordering before 5.18 is the default version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest course of action would be to either build from source using [`App::perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-perlbrew/), or [on your own](http://www.cpan.org/src/5.0/perl-5.18.0.tar.gz) if you absolutely must have the very latest version. ActivePerl is only up to version 5.16, and [Rawhide](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/development/rawhide/) still only has 5.16 in its repository (source and compiled), so I'm afraid you're on your own for a little while.